# expiration time of cookies

Tags: php, cookies, browser, youtube

This is the YouTube cookies in my browser

```
f2=8000000&f3=800&f1=50000000&fv=11.1.102
```

How can I find out Which part of the expiration time.

and Is it possible to be an endless cookie expiration time ?

Comment: Can you specifically address what you want to do?
Like you want to use the cookie in a php script?
Or you want to use it in java-script of a browser plugin?

Comment: i want to use this in php script (cURL)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be answered in three different ways depending on what you're exactly asking.

1) The expiration time is not set in the cookie itself, but during the request that the server sends to your browser to save the cookie. If you want to change one of your current cookies to  not expire for a very long time, say in 25 years, you would need to check how your browser saves cookies and how to modify them. Google Chrome and Firefox both provide plugins to do this.

2) However, since you reference `PHP` in your tags, I believe you're asking how to set a cookie to have an expiration date very far in advance using PHP. You would do this with the `setcookie()` function. For example, you could do something like

`setcookie('name_of_cookie', 'value_of_cookie', time()+60*60*24*365*25);`

would set a cookie with your values to expire in 25 years.

3) If you want to change a Youtube cookie, or any cookie really, that doesn't belong to your website/domain, you really can't. Most modern web browsers will not allow you to update a cookie from a different domain, to help prevent cross site requests. In other words, you can't change what you don't own.

Answer (score 0):

Browser should respect web site demanding expire time for cookies, but if you are implementing in php, you don't have to care about it.

```
f2=8000000&f3=800&f1=50000000&fv=11.1.102
```

There are 4 cookies here, f2, f3, f1 and fv, no expiration info here.
You only have to assign them using curl_setopt

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "f2=8000000;f3=800;f1=50000000;fv=11.1.102");
```

As long as you always set them, they are cookies with endless expire time.